# AFNetworking files missing in compile sources

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

AFNetworking files not showing up in compile sources after importing the AFNetworking folder into the project. If i add it from there it works but it will import new AFNetwork files which already exist in my project. what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the *.m files to the target.

[image]